# How to make a new table and specify a time_partitioning_field?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Previously, I was creating time partitioned tables using the command line, so I had something like:

```
bq mk --table --schema [MY SCHEMA] --time_partitioning_field the_dates --project_id=my_proj my_dataset.new_table
```

How how would I convert that code to python while specifying the `--time_partitioning_field` command? I can't find any documentation to support it.

What I have is:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_name = 'my_dataset'
table_name = 'new_table'

schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField('the_dates', 'TIMESTAMP'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('a', 'FLOAT'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('b', 'FLOAT'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('c', 'FLOAT'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('d', 'FLOAT'),

]


dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_name)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_name )
table = bigquery.Table(table_ref, schema=schema)
table = client.create_table(table)
```

Where or how do I specify the `--time_partitioning_field` flag?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use a [`CREATE TABLE` statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language#create_table_statement) instead?

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Create a table within a query with standardSQL and DDL.

For example:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TABLE `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v2.pageviews_2016` (
   datehour TIMESTAMP, wiki STRING, title STRING, views INT64
)
PARTITION BY DATE(datehour)
OPTIONS(
   description = 'Wikipedia pageviews from http://dumps.wikimedia.your.org/other/pageviews/'
   , require_partition_filter = true
 )
```

More tips:

- https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-lazy-data-loading-ddl-dml-partitions-and-half-a-trillion-wikipedia-pageviews-cd3eacd657b6